# How to infer the type pointed to by an auto pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following snippet, I use `auto` to obtain the output of `A.shape()`, which actually returns `std::size_t*`. Then I want to create an array of the same underlying data type, i.e. `std::size_t`. I struggled to figure out how to use `decltype()` in this case. The following did not work:

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

int main() {
    boost::multi_array<double, 3> A(boost::extents[5][4][2]);
    auto dims = A.shape();
    boost::array<decltype(*dims), 3> dims3;    // does not compile
}
```

However, if I create an intermediate variable `auto d0 = *dims;`, usage of `decltype(d0)` was successful:

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

int main() {
    boost::multi_array<double, 3> A(boost::extents[5][4][2]);
    auto dims = A.shape();
    auto d0 = *dims;
    boost::array<decltype(d0), 3> dims3;    // this works
}
```

Is there a better way to make this work? Preferably without having to generate an intermediate variable?

Comment: That's because `decltype(*dims)` is `std::size_t&` instead of `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the reference when using `decltype()` on the dereference operator:

```
using type = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*(A.shape()))>::type;
```

Thats because the dereferencing operator returns an lvalue reference to the underlying element pointed by the iterator (To be able to read and write on it).

Comment: It looks like there is a typo above.  Should it be `std::remove_reference`?

Comment: I find `std::decay` useful when I have an object that I want to store a copy of elsewhere, as it handles both reference stripping, removes cv, and deals with function to function pointer, and array to pointer, decays.  The last one is, I admit, questionable.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, `std::decay` is even better for my purposes, since `A.shape()` actually returns a `const std::size_t*`, so I had to use `std::remove_const` as well. `std::decay` achieves both in one go.